# Cleaner way to remove "bad" characters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unicode

I'm grabbing a bunch of data that can contain Unicode text and outputting it to a naive windows terminal that only understands cp1252. Currently I'm sanitizing (some might say neutering!) this input by doing:

```
data = data.encode(encoding='cp1252', errors='backslashreplace').decode()
```

It seems almost wasteful to encode to bytes only to decode back to a string, however. Is there a one-pass operation that will produce the same result?

Comment: Is the naive terminal one of the built-in ones, or is it custom? Python 3.5 (or 3.6, I forget which) improved Unicode support for the built-in terminals. If you can upgrade, it's worth it.

Comment: @JonahBishop I'm on 3.6. Redirecting stdout from the built-in shell still crashes the terminal, which is a requirement of the application I'm in (the redirection, not the crash! :D)